# wordpress widget prob

Tags: wordpress

I am using widgets in my wordpress theme and I need to remove the:

```
<div class="textwidget"></div>
```

that appears around the widget's content. I am using this in my function.php file:

```
    if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))
 register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Church Address',
 'before_widget' => '',
 'after_widget' => '',
 'before_title' => '<p class="bold">',
 'after_title' => '</p>',
));
```

but I need to remove the div from around the text widget's body. Is there some way to do this?

I also have another question. When I put let's say, a

tag in the before_widget and a

in the after_widget shouldn't it put a paragraph tag around the entire widget? Instead, it put them both before the entire widget.

Comment: have a look inside your templtes sidebar.php file and see were your widget is being loaded, and remove the div from there.

Comment: I'm not using the sidebar.php file. I put the code directly into the page.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your page.php the code should be something like:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Church Address') ) : ?>
<address>
     <p class="bold">
       The Church Address goes here if the sidebar isn't working or not loading
     </p>
</address>
<?php endif; ?>
```

then enable your sidebar widget: admin->appearance->widgets
the code which is inside your functions.php file should be fine. although if using the p tag, I would encompass this in an address tag for better read ability, also its supported by all the major browsers..

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))
 register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Church Address',
 'before_widget' => '',
 'after_widget' => '',
 'before_title' => '<address class="bold">',
 'after_title' => '</address>',
));
```

Comment: I know this. But whenever I use the before_widget and after_widget both tags appear before the widget instead of before and after.

Comment: can you post an example of the output'd HTML you receive 
and also the code on the page.php file.. possibly the functions.php file aswell..

Comment: it doesn't matter anymore. Thanks anyways.